# Engagement Value Points and Goals Conversion on the Sitecore Executive Insight Dashboard

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, sitecore-dms, sitecore-analytics

After creating goals and associate them with pages on Sitecore 7.2. I can't see the Goals Conversion report on the Executive Insight Dashboard. The other metrics are being filled but not the Goals Conversion. Am I missing something?

If I query the Sitecore Analytics database I can see records on the [Visitors] table, with a value different from 0 in the "Value" field (I believe that is the value filled by the configured goals), also I can see the goals triggered on the [PageEvents] table.

Other thing, is it normal each page request for the same user the same goal is  triggered and engagement value points get accumulated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could check is the `MinimumVisitFilter` setting in this file in your webroot:

`\sitecore\shell\Applications\Reports\Dashboard\Configuration.config`

By default this is set to 50 visits - you'll only get data in the dashboard if you get 50+ visits triggering the Goal.

As far as I aware the engagement value points should be accumulated in the scenario you describe - though I haven't tested this in 7.2.